# Showing on-screen keyboard in lock screen

Tags: xfce

I need `onboard` (or similar virtual keyboard) be shown in xfce lock screen. I switched to xfce because `onboard` had different problems in unity (ubuntu 21) and ubuntu-xorg interfaces

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here
https://docs.xfce.org/apps/screensaver/start
run **Screensaver preferences**

enable keyboard

[image]

**onboard -e** needs to be used to activate the onboard keyboard, if installed.